# Look for missing columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to find an easy way how to check all tables in schema where this columns doesn't exists.

So my case: In the middle of project we started adding some technical columns that needs to be in every table in that schema and I want to get list of tables that doesn't have this column.

Is there an easy way of doing that?

Comment: You can look into the view  present in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and search for the table_name and column_name. SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE table_namne in () and column_name = ('columnlooking_for);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `QUALIFY` and `COUNT_IF`:

```
USE DATABASE <db_name>;

SELECT DISTINCT c.TABLE_CATALOG, c.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA ILIKE ANY ('<SCHEMA_NAME1>', '<SCHEMA_NAME2>')
QUALIFY COUNT_IF(c.COLUMN_NAME ILIKE '<SOME_TECHNICAL_COL>')
        OVER(PARTITION BY c.TABLE_CATALOG, c.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant ways with joins, etc., but this works. If you're looking for any tables missing the columns named `ID` and `UUID` for example, you can do this:

```
select TABLE_NAME from
(select TABLE_NAME, arrayagg(COLUMN_NAME) COLS from 
     information_schema.columns group by TABLE_NAME)
where not array_contains('ID'::variant, COLS)
  or  not array_contains('UUID'::variant, COLS)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we should consider database and schema names. The columns view also returns the columns of view objects. So I wrote this one (*I'm looking for the missing "ID" column*):

```
select concat_ws( '.', table_catalog, table_schema, table_name) 
from information_Schema.tables 
where concat_ws( '.', table_catalog, table_schema, table_name) not in (
select concat_ws( '.', table_catalog, table_schema, table_name) 
from information_Schema.columns where column_name = 'ID');
```